# ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

I am using these below Cocoapods in my ios project.I have notice one awkward thing in "Other LInker Flag" that it shows with dependent (please see attachment ), can anyone help me find exact issue
  'HelpStack', 'pop', '~> 1.0'  'Bugsnag' 'CHRTextFieldFormatter''Heap'
Also attached my Linker error snapshot

I am using xcode7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is one class which has one declartion in .h file 
void AsyncDispatch(dispatch_block_t block);
and in .m

void AsyncDispatch(dispatch_block_t const block)
{
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), block);
}

and this .h file has been imported many places.If i removed this file my linker issues has been resolved.
so what i feel that this issues will create by importing your own classes .please focus on that there is no issue about cocoapods

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code

```
void AsyncDispatch(dispatch_block_t const block) { dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), block); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Update the pod file using simulator by giving path of your project to the pod file and enter command

```
pod install
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion ,Can you please little bit elaborate your suggestion as i am new in cocoapod.I don't know how to give path of project in pod file using simulator .Egerly waiting for your response as i am struggling with this from last 2 weeks .your help would be really appriciated.

Comment: Whenever you download code from the internet and the source is cocoapod based. You have to install the latest libraries. So the pod file contains information about the libraries. So when you run above code it will update the libraries.